# Access Jupyter terminal from iTerm

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, remote-access

When I start a jupyter notebook, I am able to start a terminal prompt running on the host machine with "New > Terminal".

Is it possible to connect to this terminal with, for instance, iTerm, instead of using the web interface?

How does jupyter connect to the remote terminal?

Note: I am using a remote Jupyter notebook with several port forwarding. I am not able to directly open a terminal onto this machine.